# Swift cannot convert value of type to expected argument in Realm

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I'm trying to wrap my head around the Realm API in Swift which looks extremely promising. I'm trying some demo code in their documentation and I keep getting the same error.
I have a Dog.swift file with the following:

```
import Foundation
class Dog {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

In my main ViewController.swift, I have the following to create an instance of Dog and try to save it. The issue is that the realm.add line is not compiling because it "Cannot convert value of type 'Dog' to expected argument type 'Object'"

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let myDog = Dog()
    myDog.name = "Rex"
    myDog.age = 10

    // Get the default Realm
    let realm = try! Realm()
    // You only need to do this once (per thread)

    // Add to the Realm inside a transaction
    realm.write {
        realm.add(myDog)
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import the RealmSwift framework in the Dog class instead of the Realm framework.

Comment: this is the correct answer to my question, why would it be downvoted?

Comment: I see that you wrote the answer first, so take +1.

Answer (score 6):

You should add **import RealmSwift** in your *Dog.swift* file, and then change it like this:

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
}
```

Comment: Hii, i did same thing as you mention but it's not working for me. is there any other solution for this? Thanks!